# How to reload custom table view cell after last row deletion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a simple array as data source. I designed a custom nib for a special `UITableViewCell` that is shown when the array is empty (i.e. when the app first starts).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.wallet count] == 0)
        return 1;
    else return [self.wallet count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If there isn't any coupon yet, then show the custom "No Coupon Yet" cell
    if ([self.wallet count] == 0)
        return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NoCouponCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    else {
        CouponCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CouponCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Coupon *coupon = [self.wallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell configureForCoupon:coupon];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Since I'd like to add the swipe-to-delete functionality, I provided the following method for the view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.wallet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Creates a new, temporary array holding just the one index-path item
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    // Tells the table view to delete the row with a nice animation
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmp withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

However, when the table view has only one row and I try to delete it, my app crashes. Why?

EDIT: The debug info tells that a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` is raised.

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint to your project and tell us where exactly the app crashes?

Comment: Another thing, do you also delete the item corresponding to your cell from your array when you remove the cell?

Comment: And what log does it shows when crashing

Comment: @halileohalilei The app surely crashes during the `tableView:commitEditingStyle`. I do remove the item from my data source: it's the first line of that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.wallet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView reloadData]; // reload your table to see updates

        // or if you what some animation use|

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] 
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

...

---

Here's a fix for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CouponCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[self.wallet count] == 0 ? @"NoCouponCell" : @"CouponCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.wallet count] > 0)
    {
        Coupon *coupon = [self.wallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell configureForCoupon:coupon];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This won't display my custom table view cell when the data source is empty.

Comment: @Dree, there.. i updated my answer and fixed your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1):

try this in your code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [self.wallet count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `numberOfRowsInSection` function:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

      return [self.wallet count];
}
```

And at the end of your `commitEditingStyle` function, use

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This is working (the app doesn't crash anymore), but it doesn't reload my custom cell.

Comment: To reload you can call,  [self.tableView reloadData] //use your tableview's instance name

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.wallet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Creates a new, temporary array holding just the one index-path item
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    // Tells the table view to delete the row with a nice animation
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmp withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a rowcount of 1 if your data array `wallet` has no elements:

```
 if ([self.wallet count] == 0)
        return 1;
    else return [self.wallet count];
```

But in the `commitEditingStyle` method you don't handle this case: This means that it's possible to delete the `NoCouponCell`. And I assume that the crash occurs, because you want to remove an object from your data-array which does not exist.

```
[self.wallet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Solution**: Use the following delegate method to determine when a cell can be edited: This prevents the delegate method `commitEditingStyle` to be called.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [self.wallet count] > 0
}
```

Comment: I need to return 1 when my data array has no items because I want to display a custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a view to the UITableview tableFooterView on tableview datasource, you can put your custome cell'content in this view

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (dataArray.count == 0) {
        UIView *view = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = view;
    }
    return dataArray.count;
}
```